# Why does this return an error that my variable is undefined

Tags: python, runtime-error

The question really explains my problem, trying to code a program that could split the date yet I keep encountering the same error

```
def date2():
    date = input("Please enter the date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy")
    return date
def month(date):
    month = int(date[0:3])
    return month
def day2(date):
    day = int(date[3:5])
    return day
def year2(date):
    year = int(date[5:])
    return year
def main():
    date2()
    month(date)
    day2(date)
    year2(date)
    print(month + day + year)
main()

Please enter the date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy 12/12/2017
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\DateWithoutSplit.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "H:\DateWithoutSplit.py", line 15, in main
    month(date)
NameError: name 'date' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    date = date2()
    ...
```

You didn't store the `date` variable anywhere once it was returned

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried is a kind of bad practice also the program has several other errors too.
Try the below one, which will give you the proper output. And try learning python strptime and strftime methods.

```
from datetime import datetime

def main():
   date = raw_input("Please enter the date in the form of mm/dd/yyyy")
   date = datetime.strptime(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
   print(date.month + date.day + date.year)
main()
```